# Email Formatting

Tags: theming

I'm trying to theme our emails sent by webforms. I can't figure out how to remove the default theming for our site's logo from the email body. I've copied the webform-email-message-html.html.twig file into my theme, and am able to theme the webform submission values, but I can't remove the default site logo.

Our default logo is an svg, so without being able to wrap it in some custom html and css, it displays full width of whichever email client is being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Webform itself does not add the site logo to any submission email. There must be some other module doing this, I think you are searching at the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to think that was the case. But still can't seem to locate any code that is modifying the email template.

Comment: Am I wrong or do the standard templates still apply here, like html.html.twig or page.html.twig? I recall having to override these in Drupal 7 in regards to sending emails either via drupal_mail or Webform. It sounds like that must be the case, because the template you are modifying sounds similar to say, node.html.twig.

Comment: You must be using mimemail module or similar to get HTML enabled emails. It is the template from these types of modules you need to override to change the logo. It will affect all your website emails equally unless you use some criteria to only target webform emails.

Comment: I can't find a twig file that outputs the html generated for the logo in the email. I've been searching through the database to see if I can find it there.

Comment: I'm not using mimemail. The only email related module we're using, as far as I can decipher, is smtp, and as far as I can tell, that module is not adding the logo to the email. But yes, it is being added to all emails, not just webform sent email. So maybe I'll post this question elsewhere? Thanks for all the input.

Comment: I found the answer. My mistake was that I had limited my search to twig files in a previous search. When I realized that was the case, I was able to quickly find the code that was injecting the logo into all emails. There was a module using hook_mail_alter(), adding the logo to all emails. Thanks for the input, sorry for the mistake!